# Passing variables to a Django template extended by several views

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I have a Django template `base.html` that I extend in several views. Each view adds a content block and provides the information needed to render that block.
Now I want to change `base.html` to show some system status information. Does this mean I need to update every single view to request this info from the DB and pass it into the template, or is there some better way to do it?

`base.html`

```
<body>
<div>
    {{ system.status }}
</div>
<div>
{% block content %}
{% endblock %}
</div>
</body>
```

`view1.html`, `view2.html`, `view3.html`, etc.

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<div>
    {{ view_specific.info }}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Should every view be made to provide the `system` object?

Comment: Use a [custom template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-template-tags/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks [Daniel Roseman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104349/daniel-roseman), solved it with a [custom inclusion tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags).